# Bootstrap grid проблемы верстки

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap, html

Нужна колонка шириной 8, по середине страницы.
Ниже ее во всю ширину(12) другим цветом.

Имею в итоге:

```
<div class="col-md-2 column">&nbsp;</div><div class="col-md-8 column">колонка 1 </div><div class="col-md-2 column">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-md-12 column">колонка 2</div>
```

Но почему-то нижняя колонка начинается от начала родительского div:
[image: div]
Не могу найти причину, адрес страницы http://lavds-wordpress.tw1.ru/test/
Это WP, контент поста вставляется внутри блока `<div class="blog-text">`

Так же не работает выравнивание таблиц если они пустые, поэтому поставил nbsp.

Comment: Причиной такого поведения является float: left у колонок с шириной 2. Оберните разные строки в отдельные div-ы

Comment: `<div><div class="col-md-2 column">&nbsp;</div><div class="col-md-8 column">колонка 1 </div><div class="col-md-2 column">&nbsp;</div></div>
<div><div class="col-md-12 column">колонка 2</div></div>` вы имеете ввиду так? не помогает, нижний div все так же от начала более раннего родительского.

Comment: Добавьте еще класс row этим div-ам

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Comment: И общий div с классом container добавьте

Comment: он есть в коде шаблона

Answer (score 1):

Никаких флоатов не нужно, не начинайте косячить в самом начале, есть такой класс `.col-md-offset-2` он сдвигает ваш блок на 2 секции, при условии если вы уберете секции `.col-md-2`, так же посмотрите свойства `.col-md-push-2` и `.col-md-pull-2` эти классы позволяют двигать блоки (менять местами) это альтернатива флоатов

Попробуйте так 1 вариант:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="first col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">Колонка 1 с использованием .col-xs-offset-2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="second col-xs-12">Колонка 2</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

вариант 2:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="sidebar col-xs-2">Sidebar Right</div>
  <div class="first col-xs-8">Колонка 1 с использованием .col-xs-offset-2</div>
  <div class="sidebar col-xs-2">Sidebar Right</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="second col-xs-12">Колонка 2</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Что касается `pull` и `push`. На extra small устройствах (с разрешение до 768px): 1 блок находится над вторым `col-xs-12`, на устройствах с разрешением больше или равно 768px, блоки меняют свой размер и делятся пополам `col-sm-6`, первый блок уходит вправо `col-sm-push-6`, а второй - влево `col-sm-pull-6`.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="first col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">Колонка 1 отправляем ее вправо на 6 секции .col-sm-push-6</div>
  <div class="second col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">Колонка 2 отправляем ее влево на 6 секций .col-sm-pull-6</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[Все примеры](https://jsfiddle.net/6bjw5vor/2/)

Comment: Спасибо. Это все понятно. Просто там шаблон WP,  и блоки в редакторе задаются предопределенными в функциях шорткодами, и все случаи описывать разработчикам смысла не было. Поэтому там и используется float left